# Clinical trial proplem

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

[image: ![enter image description here]

Sections 1.4.4 and 1.4.5 found binomial P-values for a clinical trial with y = 9
successes in 10 trials. Suppose instead y = 8. Using the binomial distribution
shown in Table 1.2:
a. Find the P-value for (i) Ha: π > 0.50, (ii) Ha: π < 0.50.
b. Find the mid P-value for (i) Ha: π > 0.50, (ii) Ha: π < 0.50.
c. Why is the sum of the one-sided P-values greater than 1.0 for the ordinary
P-value but equal to 1.0 for the mid P-value?

Comment: Actually, I am totally blank about this problem, have done another problem related to this but nothing will find.

Comment: I AM CONFUSED ABOUT with y = 9 successes in 10 trials. Suppose instead y = 8.